# Does changing the collation of a column change TIMESTAMP (rowversion) values?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, alter-table, collation, timestamp

I need to run

```
ALTER TABLE ... 
ALTER COLUMN ... COLLATE Czech_CI_AS ...
```

for multiple columns in a database. All those tables have `TIMESTAMP` column which is used for database synchronization.

Will the `ALTER TABLE` command that changes only `COLLATION` of a column and nothing else increment values of a `TIMESTAMP` column on SQL Server 2008 R2 Std.?

Comment: Have you tried it in a test database?

Comment: Not yet... That would certainly answer this question for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will the ALTER TABLE command that changes only COLLATION of a column and nothing else increment values of a TIMESTAMP column on SQL Server 2008 R2 Std.?

No it wont change/incement the values of timestamp column.

altering a collation is specific to that column only.

From [BOL](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260631(v=sql.80).aspx) :

> The value in the timestamp column is updated every time a row containing a timestamp column is inserted or updated.

***A word of Caution:*** You should not use `timestamp` as it is already deprecated. Instead use `rowversion`. Check out [BOL reference here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx).